Trigonometry identity help, sum of cosines
I am trying to do more advanced trigonometry problems and I found a collection online by Amir Hossein Parvardi. I have been struggling with the first problem for a few days now and I would like some hints about the solutions.
The problem is

Prove that:
$$ \cos{\dfrac{2\pi}{13}} + \cos{\dfrac{6\pi}{13}} + \cos{\dfrac{8\pi}{13}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{13}-1}{4}$$

I have tried many different approaches. I first tried just using trigonometric identities to try and transform it into something else, every manipulation lead me nowhere; then, I tried using the fact that these are the angles that the roots of unity form in the complex plane but could not find some symmetry that actually allows me to calculate it and then I tried considering the triangle obtained by plotting these roots of unity and still got nowhere.
